# Learn smoothly varying mean and variance of a variable over a 2d domain

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability, density-estimation

For a problem which I am working on at the moment, I'm interested in learning how the mean and variance of some response variable `y` changes with two independent variables `x1` and `x2` - i.e. for each coordinate in (`x1`, `x2`)-space I wish to have an estimate for $\mu_y$ and $\sigma_y$ in order to be able to approximately standardise new observations as they arrive.

I have enough domain knowledge to expect both the mean and variance of `y` to vary smoothly across this space (plus I can likely place bounds on the gradient at any point), which I'd like to use to be able to deal with previously-unseen `x1`, `x2` pairs as they arise.

What techniques would you suggest for such a problem?